# NLB IIS Integrated security asks for credentials?

Tags: iis, nlb

I have a 2 node NLB running IIS.  Servers are identical in every respect.  When on the server I can browse to the local Windows Integrated Security site without any problems using the local member name.  But when I switch to it's cluster name, it prompts me for credentials.

<- Renders just fine
 <- Renders just fine

<- Prompts for credentials

Certificates aren't the issue.  Non WI-Security sites work just fine.

Seems like it doesn't want to pass credentials across the cluster name (and most likely right back into the same server I am on.  I did try a couple of affinity settings with no change).

Thanks all for any ideas.

Nick

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the way Kerberos delegation works with Windows Integrated security.

In short, here's what you'll need to do:

- Set the identify of the application pool running your website to a domain user, on all IIS servers participating in the NLB cluster
- Ensure this domain account is in the IIS_USRS group on each web server
- Create an SPN entry for your NLB cluster DNS name, and the domain user. For example:

  setspn -S HTTP/ domain\accountname

Following this, you should be able to access your site without additional prompt for credentials. 
A more detailed explanation is available here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2006/12/08/enabling-kerberos-delegation-on-a-nlb-scenario/

Comment: Actually, what I was wondering if it would be simply because it doesn't know where it is.  I wonder if I could also fix this by creating a hosts entry for my cluster name, either as a cname or an a record right back to my own member name...

Comment: You said that non-Windows Integrated sites work fine using the cluster name, so I would not suspect it to be a name resolution issue, or cluster communication/load balancing problem.